# Why is my new PostgreSQL database not empty?

Tags: postgresql

Whenever I create a new database from pgAdmin or using the command line (using CREATE DATABASE *database_name*), it's not empty.

It contains some tables that are part of a previous project I worked on.

I'm not yet very familiar with Psql so I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have created objects in the database `template1`.

[Quote from the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdatabase.html):

> *By default, the new database will be created by cloning the standard system database template1. A different template can be specified by writing TEMPLATE name. In particular, by writing TEMPLATE template0, you can create a virgin database containing only the standard objects predefined by your version of PostgreSQL. This is useful if you wish to avoid copying any installation-local objects that might have been added to template1.*

So, anything that is in the `template1` database will be copied over to the new database when you run `create database`.

Connect to the `template1` database and drop all objects you don't want.

Comment: Thanks man! That did it. I can't seem to find the right question to ask google.

Thank You very much!