# Dropped postgres tables recreated when database dropped and recreated

Tags: postgresql, drop-table

I'm trying to programatically create and drop databases for testing purposes in Postgres.  I can't for the life of me get it to actually make the tables go away when I run DROP TABLE commands, though, and it's causing my script to fail (via 'relation already exists') when I go to create a table for a second round of tests.  I'm really stumped, mostly because it seems like postgres is not giving me a real idea of what state it is in at any given point in time.

Here is an example of the kind of thing I'm running into.  I've created a temporary testing database, that has some tables in it, then I deleted all the tables.  You can see from the first command that Posgres does not think there are any tables in there.  Switching away from the empty database, dropping that database, but then recreating it, will cause the tables I just deleted to mysteriously re-appear.

```
tmptest=> \d
Did not find any relations.
tmptest=> \c maindb;
Password for user user1: 
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), server 10.4)
SSL connection (...)
You are now connected to database "maindb" as user "user1".
maindb=> drop database tmptest;
DROP DATABASE
maindb=> create database tmptest;
CREATE DATABASE
maindb=> \c tmptest;
Password for user user1: 
psql (10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), server 10.4)
SSL connection (...)
You are now connected to database "tmptest" as user "user1".
tmptest=> \d
                  List of relations
 Schema |           Name           |   Type   | Owner 
--------+--------------------------+----------+-------
 public | test_entity              | table    | user1
```

What is going on here?  Are the drop commands not committing for some reason? How can I make tables go away for real?

Comment: you probably created those tables in the template database as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25565721

Comment: You, my friend, are a gentlehorse and a saint.  If you want to put your answer into an actual answer, I will mark it as the correct solution.  Thanks!